# linuXploit_crew hit my webserver

Tags: windows, iis, nt

We run an old Windows NT Machine, fully patched running IIS4.0.

Today we were hit by "linuXploit_crew", and they took down our websites for a minute or two. (luckily we were quick to notice a change on the websites and fix it within minutes of the attack).

However -- After fixing the website, I'm left with trying to figure out ***HOW*** this happened.

Looking in our FTP Logs, there's no changes in our default.asp files, and I see nothing out of the ordinary for Web Logs.   Any ideas on how to pinpoint how they got in?  We've only got 3 ports open, FTP, HTTP, and HTTPS (21,80,443) on a Cisco Firewall.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NT/IIS4 no longer get security updates.  Any *new* exploits will remain **unpatched**.  Time to upgrade.

Once you've been "owned" enough to change your site, you can't necessarily trust your logs anymore- they could have been "cleaned" by the attacker.

Comment: Just to add to this, Windows server 2008 web edition is only about $350.

Comment: But won't run on any hardware available at the same time NT4 was on sale.

Answer (score 0):

IIS 7 + .NET 3.5 SP1 should be a nice upgrade :)

Answer (score 0):

They appear to be using some form of Injection Attack: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355989.aspx?ppud=4

Answer (score 0):

A wide array of attacks are possible through just port 80. What applications are you running on the server? The number of asp- and php security holes is a magnitude higher than the number of OS/server application holes.

Answer (score 0):

Stay away with Windows NT class systems. IIS 7 might be okay for security, but the price is not up to standard. USE BSD instead or Linux with Apache. Centos if Linux and OpenBSD if BSD my suggestions.